# Why does SQL allow this strange use of an IN clause?

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL and here is a query that I just ran(from W3 schools):

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE (Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
AND NOT (CategoryID in (2 OR 3 ))
```

CategoryID is a number column, and the correct usage should be:

```
AND NOT (CategoryID in (2, 3 )) /* give me all rows where categoryID can't  be 2 or 3 */
```

So how can you say  :

```
AND NOT (CategoryID in (2 OR 3 )) /* why does SQL allow it? */
```

SOURCE - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: [Don't use w3schools - see the link as to why](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: my database (postgresql 9.3) doesn't allow it.  What db are you using?    ERROR:  argument of OR must be type boolean, not type integer

Comment: @DavidChan- something called TrySQL maybe it's a lite version of WebSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about SQL Server, always go to the source.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx

For the IN operator:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx

Here's an example from the documentation:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
FROM Person.Person AS p
    JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
WHERE p.BusinessEntityID IN
   (SELECT BusinessEntityID
   FROM Sales.SalesPerson
   WHERE SalesQuota > 250000);
GO
```

Here, the IN statement is looking at the result of a sub-query, a SELECT statement.

Let's change the WHERE clause in the sub-query pull back just two BusinessEntityIDs:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
FROM Person.Person AS p
    JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
WHERE p.BusinessEntityID IN
   (SELECT BusinessEntityID
   FROM Sales.SalesPerson
   WHERE 
      ( BusinessEntityID = 2 OR BusinessEntityID = 3 )
   );
GO
```

which is essentially

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
FROM Person.Person AS p
    JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
WHERE p.BusinessEntityID IN (2,3);
GO
```

which is the result of the sub-query's `WHERE ( BusinessEntityID = 2 OR BusinessEntityID = 3 )`, so why not allow the syntax `WHERE p.BusinessEntityID IN (2 OR 3);`?